# Profiling spark, try to understand the results

Tags: apache-spark, profiling

I've implemented a custom ShuffleManager and start to test it.
I've try to profile Spark GroupByTest test using perf.
I run the test with one executer per node and one core per executer.
I've attached perf to the YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend process and now I'm trying to understand the results.

I see that __memmove_ssse3 (libc) and StealTask::do_it (libjvm) are taking big portion of the job time (top two) even before shuffling starts.
According to perf __memmove_ssse3 (libc) is taking ~18% of the time.
StealTask::do_it (libjvm) is taking ~21% of the overall time according to perf.

When I run the test with the same parameters and Spark's default ShuffleManager I get different results:
__memmove_ssse3 ~9%
StealTask::do_it ~3%

Why Spark is making such extensive use in __memmove? it's related to the GroupByTest code (I see copy of arrays there)?
What StealTask::do_it is doing?